# How do i stop duplicate entries going into my membership database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the form validation functionality — it currently doesn't allow a user to enter incorrect username and password parameters when creating an account. But it's meant to bounce the user back to the signup screen. Instead they're brought through to the home screen, and if I use a username that's been used before it goes into the database anyway.

Signup controller:

```
class Signup extends CI_Controller {

    function Signup() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('membership');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('account/signuptitle');
        $this->load->view('account/signupview');
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    }

    function register() {

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_usernameTaken');


        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');


        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
        $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
        $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
        redirect('home');
        }


        if ($this->membership->usernameTaken($username)) {
        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('account/signuptitle');
        $this->load->view('account/signupview');
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
        } else {
        $this->load->view('shared/header');
        $this->load->view('account/signuptitle');
        $this->load->view('account/signupview');
        $this->load->view('shared/footer');
        }
    }

}
```

I think the `if ($this->membership->usernameTaken($username))` statement needs to arranged a certain way could it possibly be an else if statement?

Membership Model:

```
class Membership extends CI_Model {

    function Membership() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function newUser($username, $password) {
        $newMember = array('username' => $username,
        'password' => $password);
        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $newMember);
    }

    function usernameTaken($username) {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('membership')->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        return true;
        } else {

        return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help again folks — I've been looking at similar issues on this site but I just found them too confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe when the register function runs, only this part of the code is executed before redirection.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

    $this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
    redirect('home');
    }
```

try doing something like this.

if ($this->form_validation->run() && !$this->membership->usernameTaken($username)) {

```
    $this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
    $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
    redirect('home');
    }
```

this way it wont redirect and proceed to execute lines below it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say put those views in a template and you can load that template. It makes things look a bit neater.
Your index function should look like this

```
 function index() {
    $data['page_title'] = 'Sign up page';
    $data['central_content'] = "sign_up";
    $this->load->view('template');  
}
```

In your template don't forget to load content, like thus;

```
<?php $this->load->view($central_content);  ?>
```

Rearrange you register function to look like this;

```
function register() {
    #you should be autoloading these helpers tbh

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_usernameTaken');




    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    #Learn to use flashdata, it helps.

    if($this->membership->newUser($username, $password)){
       $this->session->set_userdata('status', 'OK');
       $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
       redirect('home');
    }

    }else{

     $this->index();
     }

}

#You specified a callback but there's no callback function in your class? Here's how you go about it.
Public function usernameTaken(){
 #callbacks should return true or false
    if ($this->membership->usernameTaken($username)) {
    return true;
    } else {
#You can set your own validation message in the case it's false.
$this->form_validation->set_message('usernameTaken', 'The selected username already exists');
return false;


    }
}
```

Your model is ok, try change the the funcs to this

```
 function newUser($username, $password) {
      $newMember = array('username' => $username,
      'password' => $password);
      return ($this->db->insert('membership', $newMember)) ? true : false;
}
function usernameTaken($username) {
   #your query, requires a select * in a case where it's clearly not needed. Little things like this slow down your query.Try,
    $query = $this->db->where('username', $username)->get('membership');
    #Also num_rows()
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? false : true;

}
```

Just wrote this on here, so you'd have to test it out, but i'm sure it should be fine. Sorry i could't indent it properly though, it's a pain to do it on here :)

Answer (score 0):

The form validation probably doesn't have access to the model. Try moving `usernameTaken($username)` to the controller.

Comment: Wouldnt it not see the model thorugh this command -$this->load->model('membership'); if i added it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are inserting every time.

```
if (! $this->membership->usernameTaken($username)) 
{
  $this->membership->newUser($username, $password);
}
```